# ¿Cómo automatizar histogramas de ggplot2 con múltiples variables en un Rrmakdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Estoy trabajando en la automatización de informes con Rmarkdown y por algún motivo no puedo automatizar los plots que resumen las variables. Quiero una función que pasándole un data.frame con solo variables numéricas, me cree un sub-apartado en el output para cada variable con el histograma de la variable. he probado la siguiente función:

```
summary_markdown <- function(df_numericas){
  for(vars in names(df_numericas) ){
    cat("## ",vars,"\n")
    ggplot(df_numericas, aes_string(vars)) + geom_histogram()
    cat("\n \n")
  }
}
```

y tan solo me retorna el nombre de las variables.

En cambio si pruebo con la función de histograma básica si funciona:

```
summary_markdown <- function(df){
  for(vars in names(df) ){
    cat("## ",vars,"\n")
    hist(df[,vars])
    cat("\n \n")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de un bucle no funciona la llamada implícita a `print` para `ggplot`, así que hay que hacerla explícita. Va una solución reproducible con las numéricas de `mtcars`.

```
library(tidyverse)
summary_markdown <- function(df_numericas){
  for(vars in names(df_numericas) ){
    cat("## ",vars,"\n")
    p = ggplot(df_numericas, aes_string(vars)) + geom_histogram()  #Asigno nombre
    print(p)    #imprimo el objeto asociado al nombre
    cat("\n \n")
  }
}

summary_markdown(mtcars[sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)])
```

Sin usar bucles se puede hacer una lista de data.frame por cada variable, luego generar una lista de gráficos y finalmente imprimirla.

```
mtcars %>% 
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  map(enframe) %>%     #Para hacer una lista de data.frame, si no es una lista de vectores
  imap(~ggplot(.x, aes(x = value)) +   #imap hace disponibles a los nombres de la lista como .y
  geom_histogram() + labs(title = .y)  #acá uso .y para el títutlo del gráfico
  ) -> lista_gráficos
```

Por último usamos una función anónima para generar los títulos con `cat()` e imprimir los gráficos. Hay que escapar el chunk con `results='asis'`.

```
iwalk(lista_gráficos, function(.x, .y){
  cat(paste0("## ", .y)) #Aquí dentro cada gráfico se llama .x y cada nombre .y
  print(.x)}             #y puedes agregar más funciones
  )
```

El resultado es más o menos el mismo, en este caso se usaría un paradigma funcional

Comment: esta casi perfecto, el resultado es lo deseado, pero como puedo intercalar los "##" en el print para generar un sub apartado en el markdown para cada variable?

Comment: Fíjate en la última edición que soluciona ese problema.